Equal vectors acting on the same object
Two vectors A and B have equal magnitude, equal direction and are acting on the same point
of an object.

Are A and B said to be the same vector, as in there is only one vector?
If not, and there are two distinct vectors A and B, is the magnitude of force acting on
the object equal to the sum of magnitudes of A and B?
How do we represent this situation with a diagram?
Is there any difference between this situation and one where there is a vector X acting on the same point on the same object, having the same direction but having double the magnitude? If so, what is the difference?

